# Data node demon not running on CDH 4.2.1 pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I am running hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.2.1 on CentOS in pseudo deistributed mode. When I issued the command sudo jps I don't see datanode demon up and running.

Below is the error log that I got in log file http://localhost:50070/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-localhost.localdomain.log
in NameNode:

```
**2015-05-12 04:35:26,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683 (storage id DS-1842390259-127.0.0.1-50010-1431419699539) service to /0.0.0.0:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2015-05-12 04:35:28,573 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683 (storage id DS-1842390259-127.0.0.1-50010-1431419699539) service to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8020
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "0.0.0.0":8020; 
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:760)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1229)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at $Proxy10.registerDatanode(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at $Proxy10.registerDatanode(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.register(BPServiceActor.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:660)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:243)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:156)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:409)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:276)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:760)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:288)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:752)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcPayloadHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcPayloadHeaderProtos.java:985)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:938)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:836)
2015-05-12 04:35:28,578 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683 (storage id DS-1842390259-127.0.0.1-50010-1431419699539) service to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8020
2015-05-12 04:35:28,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683 (storage id DS-1842390259-127.0.0.1-50010-1431419699539)
2015-05-12 04:35:28,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Removed bpid=BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683 from blockPoolScannerMap
2015-05-12 04:35:28,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Removing block pool BP-539882958-127.0.0.1-1386722652683
2015-05-12 04:35:30,597 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2015-05-12 04:35:30,600 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
2015-05-12 04:35:30,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/**
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: @abarisone Actually I was running the CDH 4.2.1 VM file in my Windows 8 machine which has VM player. Now when I started the cloudera VM and trying out file transfers from local file system (Cent OS) to HDFS the file copy was failing. I then issued sudo jps command to check if all the demons are running and found that datanode demon is not running. I restarted the hadoop as well but then also no use. There after I checked the NameNode logs which I pasted above which is giving as above. I tried checking the error but still struggling.